# WPF 3D graphic loop takes too long

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d-rendering

I'm trying to create goldbergs polyhedra, but the code that should draw it on my screen works too slow (about 22 seconds to draw 6th lvl of detalization)

```
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        var hexes = sphere.hexes.ToArray();

        sw.Start();

        for (int j = 0; j < hexes.Length; j++)
        {
            MeshGeometry3D myMeshGeometry3D = new MeshGeometry3D();

            Vector3DCollection myNormalCollection = new Vector3DCollection();

            foreach (var verts in hexes[j].Normals)
            {
                myNormalCollection.Add(verts);
            }

            myMeshGeometry3D.Normals = myNormalCollection;

            Point3DCollection myPositionCollection = new Point3DCollection();

            foreach (var verts in hexes[j].Normals)
            {
                myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(verts.X, verts.Y, verts.Z));
            }

            myMeshGeometry3D.Positions = myPositionCollection;

            Int32Collection myTriangleIndicesCollection = new Int32Collection();

            foreach (var triangle in hexes[j].Tris)
            {
                myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(triangle);
            }

            myMeshGeometry3D.TriangleIndices = myTriangleIndicesCollection;                

            Material material = new DiffuseMaterial(
                            new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)); ;

            if (switcher)
            {
                material = new DiffuseMaterial(
                            new SolidColorBrush(Colors.BlueViolet)); 
            }

            switcher = !switcher;

            GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D(
                myMeshGeometry3D, material);

            myGeometryModel.Geometry = myMeshGeometry3D;

            myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(model);

            myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(myGeometryModel);                
        }

        sw.Stop();
```

I've tried to make my loop parallel, but `myGeometryModel` and `myModel3DGroup` are in the main thread so i can't modify them.

Comment: I tried a different approach you might find interesting. Updated my answer.

Comment: Have you tried doing a performance profile on this in Visual Studio to see exactly which method calls are taking the most time? Believe it or not that DOES sometimes produce useful info. Then you could focus on eliminating or reducing those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't the problem.

I tried it out (thanks for posting a link) and based on what I was seeing in the Visual Studio performance tools tried using the `Model3DCollection` constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<Model3D>`, instead of adding them one by one, which I see Andy also suggested. (During the build loop I added all the models to my own `List<Model3D>` - which took almost no time - and sourced the `Model3DCollection` with this list - which is where everything ground to a halt.)

While this approximately halved the time, it was still 20+ seconds on my souped up machine in debug mode. The `Model3DCollection` constructor with the `IEnumerable` - one line of code - took up nearly all the time.

For what it's worth - and I assume you know this, but for everyone else's benefit - detail level 5 rendered about 4x as fast for me, with 20,485 elements in the collection vs. 81,925 at level 6, while level 4 was essentially instantaneous at 5125 elements. So apparently every detail level quadruples your model count and in turn the time to construct the `Model3DCollection`. Point being, if you can get away with a lower detail level the render times improve dramatically.

But if you require that detail level, you really need to be looking at another platform IMO. C# itself is not the issue, but the bottleneck is in WPF, so you're rather stuck. If you need to stick with WPF, you might try looking into `D3DImage` and `SharpDX`. No C++ is required. Of course it would be a substantial re-write, but you're virtually certain to get the performance you're looking for.

Comment: I have powerfull enough PC so my 7th lvl generates for just 50s. The main idea of this project is to generate the most detalized goldbergs polyhedra and store all of this data into database to let other people use this data itno their projects. So i need WPF just to wath the result of triangulation

Comment: Ahh ok. Then yeah, this seems sufficient for your application.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Experiment with code.

I added the following code to the end of the generation:

```
        myViewport3D.Children.Add(myModelVisual3D);

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"e:\temp\3dg.xaml", settings);
        XamlWriter.Save(myViewport3D, writer);
```

This results in a file roughly 79 meg and of course does not speed the generation up at all.

I then load that file instead of generating it:

```
    private void CreateHexaSphere(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"e:\temp\3dg.xaml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            myViewport3D = (Viewport3D)XamlReader.Load(fs);
        }
        this.Content = myViewport3D;
        return;
```

That takes roughly 7 seconds to show the sphere. Yep. Bit of a difference there.

If you are happy to just load that file from disk then 7 seconds seems way better than 52 seconds.

If you need to generate this thing on the fly then I would find a way to work with strings and build a similar string to what you get in that file.

Unsuccessful theory:

I think all the things that matter there are freezables.

.Freeze() a freezable and you increase performance but can also pass it from one thread to another.

You could do most of this on multiple parallel background threads.

EG each hex could be built on a set of parallel worker threads.  Each building their own myMeshGeometry3D which was frozen and returned to a caller thread.

Loosely, you'd have a Task DoMeshGeom3D(int j) which returns one of your 3d geometries.

You could use plinq or task.whenall or parallel.foreach

Roughly

```
 var taskList = new List<Task<MeshGeometry3D>>();

 for (int j = 0; j < hexes.Length; j++)
 {
    taskList.Add(DoMeshGeom3D(j));
 }

 var result = await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToList());
```

Grab your list of numerous MeshGeometry3D and assemble them all together.

And you could be awaiting that on a background thread in another task.

You can also try constructing your 3dgroup using a list or ienumerable of these things constructed in the separate threads rather than adding one at a time.

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2020/09/11/run-tasks-in-parallel-using-net-core-c-and-async-coding/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: `myGeometryModel.Geometry=myMeshGeometry3D;``myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(model);``myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(myGeometryModel);` are the most expensive operations, i've tried your solution but it didn't help

Comment: @goner243 did you try the constructor of the 3dgroup that takes an ienumerable?  Build the MeshGeometry3D in parallel. create the group using a list or ienumerable of those all at once rather than adding one at a time.

Comment: tried, but in needs Model3D  and i have GeometryModel3D

Comment: Could you post the full code?

Comment: Full code is here https://github.com/goner243/3dRender2

Comment: I see what you mean. 58 seconds on my i5. Ouch !

Comment: yea, it's really expensive and cuz of this i want to make it multithreaded somehow. And take care, I didn't set the limit of threads on the hex generation

Comment: I think it might be a lot faster to build this as a string then xamlreader.parse() it into a wpf object in one go.